# How to mount vmhgfs with 32 bit inodes in a 64 bit VM?

Tags: vmware-workstation, 32bit-64bit

I have following environment. Windows 10 host with VMWare Workstation 17 Pro, and a CentOS 6 VM with a shared folder. In the CentOS VM runs a 32 bit program that wants to access a file on the mounted share. It seems to me, that when the inode of a file is only representable in 64 bits, accessing the file fails.

Is there a possibility to enforce 32 bit inodes on such a mount?

For NFS mounts there you can set the kernel parameter nfs.enable_inode64 to 0.

In case of cifs you can set the mount parameter noserverino.

There are mount types that accept the mount option inode32.

For vmhgfs I found nothing.

And please, don't question the environment itself. It is a legacy environment, which I cannot change.

Comment: How did you identify the problem of 32 bit inodes? Is it apparent when tracing file related library calls such as with   ltrace -S ?